# HIVE_STATS_JDBC_TIMEOUT for Hive queries in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I've just setup a new hadoop 3.0 cluster with Hive 2.3.2 and Spark 2.3. When I want to run some queries on Hive tables, getting following error.

I know there were some bugs in Hive, but seems like it was fixed for 2.1.1, but not sure what's the situation with 2.3.2 version. Do you have any idea if that could be handled somehow?

Thanks

```
Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import spark.sql
import spark.sql

scala> sql("show databases")
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_STATS_JDBC_TIMEOUT
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.formatTimeVarsForHiveClient(HiveUtils.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:638)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: I've connected to metastore service thru thrift instead of JDBC.

Comment: the same issue for version 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I am running spar 2.3 with Hive 2.3.2 and encounter similar issue.

The fix you mentioned is for Hive 2.1 as can be seen from the Spark Jira following：

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13446

You can see from the latest comment that people are getting exactly same error as yours.

Also, as this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522857/apache-spark-2-2-0-not-able-to-connect-to-metastore-after-upgrading-hive-metasto) question answered, the current Hive version supported by Spark is 2.1